# Grid with header row and usercontrol for rows (columns)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following control, the first row is a header row. There will always be at least one additional row. (minimum of 2 total rows).

I've thought about making the content row into a UserControl but unsure about how to set the content of the UserControl into the two columns. (Stack in Column 0 and TriggerForWord in Column 1)

What is the best way to implement adding rows dynamically and setting the content? UserControl loaded into each row? Something else?

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,10,10,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.WordToTriggerAction}}" Margin="2 8 2 8"  FontWeight="SemiBold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.Trigger}}" Margin="12 8 2 8"  FontWeight="SemiBold" />
        <!-- dynamic part --> 
        <StackPanel x:Name="Stack" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="WordForAction" Width="300" WatermarkContent="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.EnterWordForAction}}" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Words}"
            DisplayMemberPath="word" SelectionMode="Single" AutoCompleteMode="Append" SearchTextChanged="WordForAction_SearchTextChanged" />
            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SearchText.Length, ElementName=WordForAction}" IsTabStop="False" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=WordForAction}" FontFamily="{StaticResource TelerikWebUI}" FontSize="15" Content="{StaticResource GlyphPlus}" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.AddWord}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SearchText.Length, ElementName=WordForAction}" IsTabStop="False" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=WordForAction}" FontFamily="{StaticResource TelerikWebUI}" FontSize="15" Content="{StaticResource GlyphMinus}" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.RemoveWord}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </StackPanel>
        <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="TriggerForWord" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" EmptyText="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.Trigger}}" IsEditable="False" IsEnabled="False" SelectedValuePath="uuid" SelectionChanged="TriggerForWord_SelectionChanged"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=WordForAction, Path=ActualHeight}" Margin="10 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Triggers}" DisplayMemberPath="description" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a UserControl if you intend to replace its content anyway?

Comment: Like I said I'm struggling to understand how to do this - I imagine adding rows in code, and then add an instance of the usercontrol to each row. The usercontrol would only be for the content row.

Comment: hopefully modified question is clearer.

Comment: You may want to consider using an ItemsControl and bind its ItemsSource property to an IEnumerable<YourType>. Then a row per YourType object will be rendered automatically in the view.

Comment: @mm8 Went with ItemsControl as a row in the grid - thanks

Answer (score 0):

For other folks who come this way ...

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="310"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.WordToTriggerAction}}" Margin="2 8 2 8"  FontWeight="SemiBold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.Trigger}}" Margin="2 8 2 8"  FontWeight="SemiBold" />
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WordsForAction}" x:Name="WordsForActionItems" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310">
                            <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="WordForAction" Width="250" WatermarkContent="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.EnterWordForAction}}" Margin="0" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Words, ElementName=_this}" DisplayMemberPath="Word" SearchText="{Binding Word}"
                                SelectionMode="Single" AutoCompleteMode="Append" SearchTextChanged="WordForAction_SearchTextChanged" />
                            <Button Name="AddWord" IsEnabled="True" IsTabStop="False" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=WordForAction}" FontFamily="{StaticResource TelerikWebUI}" FontSize="15" Content="{StaticResource GlyphPlus}" Click="AddWord_Click" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.AddWord}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                            <Button Name="RemoveWord" IsEnabled="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=WordsForActionItems, Converter={StaticResource CountToBoolConverter}}" IsTabStop="False" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=WordForAction}" FontFamily="{StaticResource TelerikWebUI}" FontSize="15" Content="{StaticResource GlyphMinus}" Click="RemoveWord_Click" ToolTip="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.RemoveWord}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TriggerForWord" Width="150" EmptyText="Trigger" IsEditable="False" IsEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="TriggerForWord_SelectionChanged"
                            Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Triggers, ElementName=_this}" SelectedValuePath="uuid" DisplayMemberPath="description" SelectedValue="{Binding Trigger_uuid}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```